sed (or awk): print captured group or placeholder if it doesn't exist
So since GitHub removed the insights tab for non-premium accounts, I'm trying to locally list insertions and deletions to my git repository per day.
I figured out this way of printing what I want:
git log --pretty="@%ad" --date=short --shortstat |  tr "\n" " " | tr "@" "\n"

That produces this kind of output:
2024-06-13   7 files changed, 400 insertions(+), 406 deletions(-) 
2024-06-12   3 files changed, 145 insertions(+) 
2024-06-12   5 files changed, 638 deletions(-) 
2024-06-12   1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-) 

Notice the plurals in file(s), insertion(s) and deletion(s). Another problem is that a commit might not have insertions or deletions (or both, but let's ignore this case).
So I'm almost there, I just need to extract the date, insertions and deletions and group by date. That will produce some sort of "work done per day" graph.
I made this regex to capture the fields dealing with all the optionals:
/^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s{3}[0-9]+\sfile(s)?\schanged,\s(([0-9]+)\sinsertion(s)?\(\+\))?(,\s)?(([0-9]+)\sdeletion(s)?\(\-\))?\s$/gm

Now I need to get the 1st, 4th and 8th groups, for instance with sed:
echo "2024-06-13   7 files changed, 400 insertions(+), 406 deletions(-) " |
    sed -r 's/^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s{3}[0-9]+\sfile(s)?\schanged,\s(([0-9]+)\sinsertion(s)?\(\+\))?(,\s)?(([0-9]+)\sdeletion(s)?\(\-\))?\s$/\1 \4 \8/gm'

That produces the correct output:
2024-06-13 400 406

But if the input string doesn't have insertions or deletions, sed just prints nothing for that captured group. Eg.:
2024-06-13 400

And I have no way to tell if the single number are insertions or deletions.
Is there anyway to extract the groups from each line, but print a "0" as placeholder if the group doesn't exist? (not necessarily with sed alone, and not necessarily in a single command).

-r is the option in old versions of GNU sed only to enable EREs. In current versions of GNU sed, BSD sed, and in the latest POSIX standard for sed the option to enable EREs is -E, same as for grep, not `-r.

tr "\n" " " turns your data into something that's no longer a valid text file per POSIX so, in general, don't do that. If you post the output from git log --pretty="@%ad" --date=short --shortstat and the final output you want given that input then we can help you.

--pretty=%ad --date=short is the same as --pretty=%as, so just use the latter.

There are always many solutions possible. Here is one. I like a single regexp that does everything, but sometimes it is best to keep it simple and step by step:
sed -r '
/^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) /{
  s/$/XXX C0 I0 D0/
  s/([0-9]+)( files? changed.*)C0/\2C\1/
  s/([0-9]+)( insertion.*)I0/\2I\1/
  s/([0-9]+)( deletion.*)D0/\2D\1/
  s/ .*XXX//
  s/[CDI]//g
}
'

This matches the date, then adds to the end of the line the placeholder string "XXX C0 I0 D0". The next 3 commands then replace the appropriate 0 by the real number of changed, inserted, or deleted items.
The whole line from the end of the date until the placeholder is removed, and the C, D, and I letters are removed, leaving just the updated numbers attached to them.

This is amazing. I've based my answer in this approach.

If the intermediate placeholder is empty you'll have a double space, which you can fill with a zero. Likewise if you have no last item your line will end with a space.
echo "2024-06-13   7 files changed, 400 insertions(+), 406 deletions(-) " |
    sed -r \
        -e 's/^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s{3}[0-9]+\sfile(s)?\schanged,\s(([0-9]+)\sinsertion(s)?\(\+\))?(,\s)?(([0-9]+)\sdeletion(s)?\(\-\))?\s$/\1 \4 \8/gm' \
        -e 's/  / 0 /' -e 's/ $/ 0/'


It might be more reliable if you use --numstat and calculate the required stats yourself. Using --numstat (e.g., in git log --numstat --pretty="@%ad" --date=short) results in output like:
@2024-06-07

1       1       plugin/supertab.vim
@2024-06-07

2       34      plugin/supertab.vim
@2024-06-06

7       1       plugin/supertab.vim
@2021-04-22

4       0       .gitignore
17      0       Makefile
210     0       README.rst
473     0       doc/supertab.txt
61      0       ftplugin/html.vim
45      0       ftplugin/xml.vim
1144    0       plugin/supertab.vim

Then you can use something like the following awk code:
/^@[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/ { # new commit info starting with `@<date>`
  if (date) {  # print previous commit's stats
    print date, inserts, deletes
  };
  date = $0;
  getline;
  inserts = deletes = 0;  # reset counts
  next
}
{
  inserts += $1;
  deletes += $2;
}
END {
  if (date) {  # Final (initial?) commit
    print date, inserts, deletes
  }
}

Example output:
% git log --numstat --pretty="@%ad" --date=short | awk '/^@[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/ {if (date) {print date, i, d}; date=$0; getline; i=d=0; next} {i+=$1; d+=$2; } END {if (date) {print date, i, d}}' | head
@2024-06-07 1 1
@2024-06-07 2 34
@2024-06-06 7 1
@2021-04-22 1954 0

If you want to combine the stats for all commits on the same day, you can instead use something like:
if (date == $0) {
  getline; next
}
if (date) {
  # print previous commit's stats
  #...
}

So:
% git log --numstat --pretty="@%ad" --date=short | awk '/^@[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/ {if (date == $0) { getline; next } if (date) {print date, i, d}; date=$0; getline; i=d=0; next} {i+=$1; d+=$2; } END {if (date) {print date, i, d}}' | head
@2024-06-07 3 35
@2024-06-06 7 1
@2021-04-22 1954 0


Yes, I later knew about numstats and it was about as difficult to parse. But I wanted to learn how to sanitize input with default values anyway.

We can insert 0 insertions after "changed" if it's missing:
/insertion/!s/changed,/& 0 insertions(+),/

Similarly, we can append 0 deletions if that's necessary:
/deletion/!s/$/, deletions(-)/


Complete script
Pipe the output of git log --pretty=%as --shortstat into this small program (no need for @ in format or for tr commands):
#!/usr/bin/sed -Ef

# Store date line in hold space
/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}/h

# Ignore everything except shortstat lines
/changed/!d

# Add insertions if absent
/insertion/!s/changed,/& 0,/
# Add deletions if absent
/deletion/!s/$/, 0/

# Reformat
s/.* changed,//
s/[^0-9,]+//g

# Prepend the saved date
H
x
y/,\n/  /


Using a single call to any awk in any shell on every Unix box, this
git log --pretty="@%ad" --date=short --shortstat |
awk '
    sub(/^@/,"") { date = $0 }
    gsub(/s?\([+-]),?/,"") {
        delete val
        val[$5] = $4
        val[$7] = $6
        print date, val["insertion"]+0, val["deletion"]+0
    }
'

will produce this output:
2024-06-13 400 406
2024-06-12 145 0
2024-06-12 0 638
2024-06-12 1 1

Here's a commented version of the above script to help explain what it does:
sub(/^@/,"") {          # Try to remove a leading `@` from the current line.
                        # If that succeeded then a leading `@` was present so
                        # this must be a date line so enter this subsequent
                        # action block.

    date = $0           # Save the date, i.e. whats left on the line once
                        # the above `sub()` removed the leading `@`.
}

gsub(/s?\([+-]),?/,"") {#  Try to remove a string that contains `(+)` or `(-)`
                        # optionally preceded by `s` or followed by `,` so
                        # `insertion(+)`, `insertions(+),` or similar become
                        # `insertion` and `deletions(-),` etc. become `deletion`.
                        # If that succeeded then this is a line containing
                        # insertion and deletion values to process them.

    delete val          # Remove the `val` array to ensure no it cannot contain
                        # leftover valus from processing the previous line.

    val[$5] = $4        # $5 contains `insertion` or `deletion` or is empty
                        # so save the mapping from that to the value thats
                        # in $4 so we have e.g. `val["insertion"] = 400`.

    val[$7] = $6        # Ditto for $7 and $6.

    print date, val["insertion"]+0, val["deletion"]+0
                        # Print the saved values in the order we want them
                        # to be output. Adding `0` means if `insertion` and/or
                        # deletion were missing from the input and so `val[]`
                        # wasnt populated for them on this line, wed still
                        # print `0` instead of a null string.
}

I see from your answer though that you actually want to sum the values per date - if so then this, again using any awk:
git log --pretty="@%ad" --date=short --shortstat |
awk '
    sub(/^@/,"") {
        date = $0
        if ( (date != prev) && (prev != "") ) {
            print prev, val["insertion"]+0, val["deletion"]+0
            delete val
        }
        prev = date
    }
    gsub(/s?\([+-]),?/,"") {
        val[$5] += $4
        val[$7] += $6
    }
    END {
        print prev, val["insertion"]+0, val["deletion"]+0
    }
'

will produce this output:
2024-06-13 400 406
2024-06-12 146 639

without having to store all values in memory at once.
The above assumes that this:
git log --pretty="@%ad" --date=short --shortstat

produces output like this:
@2024-06-13

 7 files changed, 400 insertions(+), 406 deletions(-)

@2024-06-12

 3 files changed, 145 insertions(+)

@2024-06-12

 5 files changed, 638 deletions(-)

@2024-06-12

 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)


Interesting use of strings to index awk arrays. Btw would you mind explaining how does your first block handle commits with no insertions or no deletions? I see zeros correctly appearing in the output, but can't decipher what is going on.

@MisterSmith I added a commented version of that first script to my answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Complete solution based on @meuh 's regex, but ignoring the number of changed files:
git log --pretty="@%ad" --date=short --shortstat |  tr "\n" " " | tr "@" "\n" |
 tail -n +2 |
 sed -r '
/^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) /{
  s/$/XXX I0 D0/
  s/([0-9]+)( insertion.*)I0/\2I\1/
  s/([0-9]+)( deletion.*)D0/\2D\1/
  s/ .*XXX//
  s/[DI]//g
}' |
 awk '{a[$1]+=$2; b[$1]+=$3} END { for (i in a) print i,a[i],b[i] }' |
 sort -k 1

The tail command in the second line is needed to remove a first empty line that the tr replacements introduce in the first line.
After that, the sed command removes everything except date, inserted lines and deleted lines, accounting for commits whith no insertions or no deletions.
Then the awk command sums the 2nd and 3rd columns grouping by the first column (date). But because awk's array keys are not ordered, we need to sort the result with a final sort by the first column, which produces the list of unique daily stats in descending order by date, eg:
2024-05-29 1234 2
2024-05-30 350 76
2024-06-03 405 68
2024-06-06 483 36
2024-06-11 447 59
2024-06-12 795 12
2024-06-13 522 436
...


Piping sed-or-grep-or-awk to sed-or-grep-or-awk is an entipattern. WHen you're using awk you don't need all of the other commands in your answer.

@EdMorton afaik sed doesn't have variables, awk is a better fit for programmatic tasks.

Yes, that's correct.

In Perl, this would be relatively simple, since you can either use integer formatting %d with printf, which will print empty values as zeroes, and/or you can use the // operator to set a "default" value:
% git ... | perl -0777 -ne '
    while (/^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s{3}[0-9]+\sfile(s)?\schanged,\s(([0-9]+)\sinsertion(s)?\(\+\))?(,\s)?(([0-9]+)\sdeletion(s)?\(\-\))?\s$/gm) {
        printf "%s %d %d\n", $1, $4//0, $8//0;
    }'  
2024-06-13 400 406
2024-06-12 145 0
2024-06-12 0 638
2024-06-12 1 1

or with s///e, which allows Perl code in the replacement part:
% git ... | perl -0777 -pe 's#^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s{3}[0-9]+\sfile(s)?\schanged,\s(([0-9]+)\sinsertion(s)?\(\+\))?(,\s)?(([0-9]+)\sdeletion(s)?\(\-\))?\s$# sprintf("%s %d %d", $1, $4//0, $8//0) #gme'
2024-06-13 400 406
2024-06-12 145 0
2024-06-12 0 638
2024-06-12 1 1

Though, as muru already mentioned, the output from --numstat might be easier to parse.

On the other hand, it may just be easier to pick each value separately, that would help avoid the gory regex. E.g. something like this, which does the daily summing at the same time:
% git ... | perl -ne '
    next unless /^([-0-9]+)\s+(\d+) files? changed/;
    $date = $1;
    $ins{$date} += $1 if /(\d+) insert/;
    $del{$date} += $1 if /(\d+) delet/;

    END {
        printf "date: %s total insertions: %d deletions: %d\n", $_, $ins{$_}, $del{$_} for sort keys %ins;
    }
'

date: 2024-06-12 total insertions: 146 deletions: 639
date: 2024-06-13 total insertions: 400 deletions: 406

Incidentally, that's rather easy to adjust so that the tr isn't needed, just set @ as the record separator:
git log --pretty="@%ad" --date=short --shortstat | perl -ne '
    BEGIN { $/ = "@" }
    next unless /^([-0-9]+)\s+\d+ files? changed/;
    $date = $1;
    $ins{$date} += $1 if /(\d+) insert/;
    $del{$date} += $1 if /(\d+) delet/;
    
    END {
        printf "date: %s total insertions: %d deletions: %d\n", $_, $ins{$_}, $del{$_} for sort keys %ins;
    }
'

(Note that the \s in your regex is Perl-ism. While GNU supports it for some reason, it's nonstandard and not supported by the standard tools on other systems.)

I don't think this does the sum grouped by date, but in any case it is useful for the first transformation. The $4//0 is exactly what I'd have needed in awk. Someone should add support for it.

@MisterSmith Regarding 'The $4//0 is exactly what I'd have needed in awk. Someone should add support for it.' - definitely not.  Instead of print ... $4//0 in the above perl script I used the equivalent of print ... $4+0 in my awk answer. The awk language is based on the doctrine that there should only be unique constructs to do things that are difficult to do with other existing constructs which is why the awk language is tiny and powerful while some other tools with many constructs get a reputation for being write-only languages so $4//0 just doesn't need to exist.

@MisterSmith, hmm. Perl's a // b is pretty much the same as defined(a) ? a : b, i.e. "if a is defined, evaluate to a, otherwise to b". It's similar to a || b, same as a ? a : b, which does the same but checks if a is a truthy value, i.e. a non-zero number or a non-empty string. (So 0 // 123 is 0, but 0 || 123 is 123.) Awk's a ? a : b works the same, but || doesn't, since it only returns zero or one, not the actual values. Awk doesn't really have a distinction between an undefined variable and one holding an empty string so the || vs. // difference is moot.

@ilkkachu in awk if ( x == 0 && x == "" ) is the test for x being an undefined variable (including unused function argument) since an undefined variable has the value 0-or-null and so matches both values while a variable that is defined and holds an empty string would fail the x == 0 part of that condition. In GNU awk you could alternatively test typeof(x) == "untyped" BUT there's a subtle difference in the case where x was mentioned but not assigned a value (e.g. y=x to unset y) as then it's type will become "unassigned" instead of "untyped" but still have the value 0-or-null.

@EdMorton, ahah, I tried to check before writing that, but the GNU awk manual wasn't too clear on it, it says "By default, variables are initialized to the empty string, which is zero if converted to a number." Well, my mistake I didn't just read the POSIX spec, it at least said it explicitly. I can't say doing (x==0 && x=="") seems too handy, though.

Anyway, the POSIX text seems to say the same should apply to nonexisting fields, but that doesn't seem to be the case. echo | awk '{ print($9 == 0) }' prints 0
in the awks I have. But gawk's typeof($9) still gives "unassigned". Umh. Honestly, I'm confused, I wonder what I'm missing.

I actually don't recall having had to use (x==0 && x=="") more than MAYBE once or twice in the past 40 years or so of using awk, I think when for some reason I had to differentiate between an optional argument passed to a function but set to a null string (foo("")) in which case I should use that value vs not provided at all (foo()) in which case I should use a global variable such as FS. Usually you know if you expect a variable to contain a string or a number and just want to test for the variable being 0 or "" so it's almost never necessary to actually write (x==0 && x=="").

Regarding echo | awk '{ print($9 == 0) }' - an input field can be either of the types unassigned, string, strnum, or numeric.  Basically, if input looks like a number it's a strnum, otherwise it's treated as a string, even if unassigned. It's only type strnum if it looks like a number and hasn't yet been "cast" (using the term loosely) to a number, e.g. by $9+=0, and only type number if has been "cast" like that. In your code $9 doesn't look like a number and so cannot be strnum or number and so is treated like a null string in the comparison.

This statement from the gawk manual summarizes it: "This point bears additional emphasis: Input that looks numeric is numeric. All other input is treated as strings."

@EdMorton, yeah, I expect it often enough works to just check for an empty string or so, and not care if the value is actually undefined. But if one needs that, I think having an explicit "undefined" value (like Perl's undef or Python's None) and a function to test is much clearer than something like (x==0 && x==""). Which has nothing to do with e.g. Perl's data structures syntax being horrible, and large regexes easily looking like unreadable line noise, or the results of someone being sick... (Then again, Perl has the /x modifier to allow whitespace and comments in REs, which helps.)

I get the strnum treatment, the confusing part was that the POSIX text says "Uninitialized variables, including scalar variables, array elements, and field variables, shall have an uninitialized value. An uninitialized value shall have both a numeric value of zero and a string value of the empty string." and then "References to nonexistent fields (that is, fields after $NF), shall evaluate to the uninitialized value."
It uses the same phrase "uninitialized value" for nonexisting fields and uninitialized variables, so I expected they'd work the same.

Well, the implementations don't work like that, and I don't know if that's an error in the standard, or if that's countered somewhere else in the text. It does seem a bit inconsistent that fields are treated differently here.

Regarding 'I think having an explicit "undefined" value (like Perl's undef or Python's None) and a function to test is much clearer than something like (x==0 && x=="")' - definitely but then you're introducing a construct to do things that, while convenient, aren't hard to do with other constructs and if you do that for this, there are a million other things, most higher impact, you could make the same argument for (a join() function for arrays, a gsub() for literal strings, etc.) and then you get code bloat leading to https://www.zoitz.com/comics/perl_small.png :-).

Regarding POSIX, the standard recently changed (see latest at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/utilities/awk.html) but I don't know if it's any clearer than the previous version in this area. It also says the following which supports your point: "Comparisons (with the '<', "<=", "!=", "==", '>', and ">=" operators) shall be made numerically: ,,, if one is numeric and the other has the uninitialized value." which is the case with your example echo | awk '{ print($9 == 0) }' so I do think there's an omission in the POSIX standard.
